# Definite article before an abstract noun

Tags: definite-articles

When is the definite article *the* appropriate before an abstract noun? In particular, I have the following examples.

Which are correct?

Case I

1. In the Theorem 4.4, we prove property A for all graphs.
2. In Theorem 4.4, we prove property A for all graphs.

Case II

1. From the Theorem 4.4, we know about property A for all graphs.
2. From Theorem 4.4, we know about property A for all graphs.

Case III

1. From the following Theorem, we know about property A for all graphs.
2. From following Theorem, we know about property A for all graphs.

Comment: You're mixing up abstract nouns and proper nouns (i.e. *names*): "Theorem 4.4" is a *proper* noun, the name of a specific object, and so does not take an article. Later, when you refer to "*Theorem*", without the *4.4* (rendering it non-specific), it's a standard noun, and so should not be capitalized, and requires an article. In that particular case, you want the definite article: "*the thereom* [we were just discussing]".

Comment: This may be better on [ell.se]

Comment: Jardine, the question itself is *required* in the body, even if stated in the title. Edited.

Comment: @DanBron The confusion may be due to the unavoidable professional blindness of a mathematician or a theoretician. To me, Theorem 4.4 is an abstract mathematical object, that I can neither see nor smell nor feel with my hands. I can only hear or read the 'statement' of the theorem, that is, how it is stated, but not the theorem itself. A theorem can be stated in many ways which might not seem to be the same thing, even though they are the same. Thanks, any how. It makes sense I believe.

Comment: Well, *love* is an abstract concept, yet it can take an article or not. Consider the following references from music: "Love is a many-splendored thing," "A Love Supreme," or "The love you take is equal to the love you make."

Comment: An example of where this might get more complicated:  in California, people often refer to highways with articles, like "the I-5" or even just "the Five" to refer to [Interstate 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstate_5).  In most other parts of the US, using an article in this manner is inappropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say, I sentence 2, II sentence 2, and III sentence 1 are correct; the latter, since dropping the in *this* case would yield a gap in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

*When is the definite article the appropriate before an abstract noun?*

When you are referring to a specific instance of that abstract noun, e.g. a specific idea or theorum, and aren't identifying it by e.g. following the noun with a number specific enough for the reader to know exactly which theorum you're discussing.

Answer (score -1):

In this very case the article **the** is referred to an abstract noun - in this case theorem -  which is already known to both speakers, i.e. they already have background knowledge about that very theorem which is determined by the article **the**.