# Referring more than one proper noun

Tags: proper-nouns

When we are referring more than one *proper* noun, then do we need to capitalize the first alphabet of it. For example: which one of the following is correct?

1) By **Theorems** 4.2 and 4.3, we can prove the following.

2) By **theorems** 4.2 and 4.3, we can prove the following.

Comment: Most people write *"Presidents Roosevelt and Truman"* rather than *"presidents Roosevelt and Truman"*. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Presidents+Roosevelt+and+Truman%2Cpresidents+Roosevelt+and+Truman&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CPresidents%20Roosevelt%20and%20Truman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpresidents%20Roosevelt%20and%20Truman%3B%2Cc0). I think this answers your question. (I was actually quite surprised by how large the minority who lowercase *"presidents"* here is, when almost nobody lowercases *"president Truman"*.)

Answer (score -1):

"theorem" is not a proper noun. Capitalization is not needed.

Comment: But "Theorem 4.2" is a proper noun, as is "Theorem 4.3". See the comments under [this related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210237/definite-article-before-an-abstract-noun), for example.

Comment: According to you. "theorem 4.2" and  "theorem 4.3" happen to be capitalized, probably because they were capitalized when used as a section heading in a textbook. That does not make "theorem" a proper noun.  It should not have been capitalized in this or the "related" question or answers.  One could refer to, say, the second chapter of a book as Chapter Two, but that does not make "chapter" a proper noun. You are correct that it does not need "the", but that is because it already carries its own qualifier, namely the number.

Comment: @Brian: by your reasoning, since *"president"* is not a proper noun, we should write *"presidents Roosevelt and Truman"* and not *"Presidents Roosevelt and Truman"*. And since *"ocean"* is not a proper noun, we should write *"Pacific ocean"*? Do I correctly understand what you're saying?

Comment: You are correct; honorifics are typically capitalized.

Comment: ... And in math textbooks, references like *"Theorem 4.2"* are typically capitalized, even in constructions like *"by Theorem 4.2, there is a ..."*.

Comment: yes, typically they are. One could use italics, or boldface, or color, or some other way to indicate that the term is a reference. The fact that they typically use capitalization in the textbook does not require others to treat it as a proper noun. Most theorems have an actual proper name (the Pythagoran Theorem, the Fundamental Theorem of Integral Calculus, etc), but the numbering of a theorem in a book is arbitrary and varies fom book to book; it is not really the "name" of the theorem.